# Xamarin Archive Build from msbuild/xbuild using the same certs and provisioning profiles fails to install

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xbuild

If I "Archive for Production" my iOS project in Xamarin Studio, I can then sign and create the IPA file. Then I upload to hockeyapp.net and my users can download and install without issue.

If I use xbuild or msbuild from the CLI with all the correct args:

`xbuild App/App.iOS.csproj /p:SolutionDir="$HOME/projects/App" /p:Configuration="Ad-Hoc" /p:Platform=iPhone /target:build /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true`

and then go into Xamarin Studio to sign and create the IPA, after uploading to hockeyapp.net my users can download but when it's installing, it will fail with a message about being unable to download.

I am using the latest Xamarin Studio and my certs and provisioning profiles are all fine.

Does anyone know what is the difference in the two methods that may be causing my error?

Comment: Are you on windows or mac?

Comment: Mac. Forgot to add that. Ugh..

Comment: Well I use windows and build android, but my build command looks like this: $(MsBuildPath) /p:Configuration=Release /t:Rebuild;SignAndroidPackage "$(CodeRootPath)\Mfx.UI.Droid\Mfx.UI.Droid.csproj". Maybe you're missing a build target (something like SignIosPackage or whatever the SignAndroidPackage equivalent is)

Comment: I do notice that the archive in "View Archives" after doing `msbuild` will show in a section titled `*Unknown*` instead of the section of the app name that Xamarin Studio archives to...

Answer (score 0):

HockeyApp is now [Visual Studio App Center](https://appcenter.ms). But your problem still exists :-).

From msbuild I know only the configuration `debug` and `release`. I don't know if your custom configuration will pick the right provisioning profiles.

You can add `CodesignKey` and `CodesignProvision` as properties to `msbuild` or `xbuild` to enforce the cert and profile, see the example here:

```
xbuild … /p:CodesignKey="iPhone Distribution: My Company (0123456789)" /p:CodesignProvision="Automatic:AdHoc" /p:platform="iPhone" /p:configuration="Release"
```